# Not able to create .txt file using Chrome

Tags: javascript

I am a novice to javascript trying to create a .txt file from an .htm document on my PC.

The following code works well with IE, and creates a file (say "A1.txt") on my desktop.  However, I can not able to create the file using Chrome. I am running Windows Vista.

Let me know what modification I need to carry out to run this code using Chrome.

Thanks in advance

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
</script></head>
<body>
<form name="F1">PN<input type="text" name="T1"></form>
<p><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="dp()"></p>
</body></html>

<script>
myObject = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
function dp()
{T1 = "";
var txtfile = "A"+document.F1.T1.value+".txt";
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var myFile = fso.OpenTextFile(txtfile,8, true,0);
myFile.write("Test");
myFile.Close();
fso = null;
}
</script>
```

Please help.

Comment: Yes, and that's why I use Chrome and avoid IE like the plague.

Comment: `ActiveXObject` only exists in old versions of IE. Use [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) instead. Please check your console for errors and the documentation available online.

Comment: To get this working on any browser except IE, you would need to have an input element for the user to pass the file into the web page, then use javascript to 'download' the file from the web page back to the user's PC.

Comment: @Xufox - xmlhttprequest wont let you write to the browsers local file system

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister - even easier is window.saveAs (in IE) - a cross browser implementation - https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/blob/master/FileSaver.js - no need to upload/download

Comment: Thanks guys. Xufox, Maximillian Laumeister, Jaromanda appreciate your time and response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the HTML5 [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/)

```
function dp() {
    if ('Blob' in window) {
        var fileName = "A" + document.F1.T1.value;
        var textToWrite = "Test";
        var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {
            type: 'text/plain'
        });

        var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
        downloadLink.download = fileName;
        downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
        if ('webkitURL' in window) {
            // Chrome allows the link to be clicked without actually adding it to the DOM.
            downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
        } else {
            // Firefox requires the link to be added to the DOM before it can be clicked.
            downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
            downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
            downloadLink.style.display = "none";
            document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
        }

        downloadLink.click();
    } else {
        alert('Your browser does not support the HTML5 Blob.');
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yntxqpk6/)

See more detailed sample [here](http://www.thewebflash.com/2014/10/reading-and-creating-text-files-using.html).